# ¿Como puedo hacer un diccionario a partir de una lista de diferentes tipos de datos en python?

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en python y necesito hacer una funcion que reciba una lista de diferentes tipos de datos como esta:

```
[560, 'a', False, 10, 23.2, True, 'x', (1, ),{'a':'a'}, [23, 'b']
```

y retorne un diccionario como este:

```
{'int': [560, 10], 'float': [23.2], 'str': ['a', 'x'], 'bool': [False, True],'tuple': [(1,)], 'list': [[23, 'b']], 'dict': [{'a': 'a'}]}
```

Actualmente pues se que dentro de la funcion puedo hacer una lista con los nombres de las llaves de esta forma:

```
lista_llaves=["int","float","str","bool","tuple","list","dict"]
```

Y se que con zip() puedo juntar ambas listas para que me quede llave,valor. La cosa es que necesito lograr que en la llave 'int' queden todos los valores tipo entero dentro de la lista, de igual forma con los demás tipos de datos pero no se como hacer que el programa detecte los datos y los organice de esa forma en el diccionario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una pregunta interesante, lo bueno es que se puede usar diccionarios y esto vuelve el trabajo mucho más fácil. Dado que un diccionario acepta como `key` un objeto inmutable, podemos usar las propias clases de los objetos como `key` y como `value` usar una lista vacía `[]`

```py
#declaramos un diccionario para hacer la "clasificacion"
tipos = {int:[], str:[],bool:[],dict:[],tuple:[],float:[],list:[]}

lista = [560, 'a', False, 10, 23.2, True, 'x', (1, ),{'a':'a'}, [23, 'b']]
#ciclo for
for element in lista:
    try:
        tipo = type(element)
        tipos[tipo].append(element)
    except:
        print(type(element),element)
```

Lo puse en un `try/except` solo para evitar problemas y saber con que elementos hay problemas. Lo que hace el ciclo es facil, pues solo obtiene el tipo de dato con `type(obj)` y busca en el diccionario si existe tal dato y lo agrega a la lista respectiva, el `except` ocurrirá si no existe el tipo de dato en el diccionario o si ocurre un error al agregarlo, el bloque del `except` se puede reemplazar por `except:pass`

**resultado**

```
{bool: [False, True],
 dict: [{'a': 'a'}],
 float: [23.2],
 int: [560, 10],
 list: [[23, 'b', [...]]],
 str: ['a', 'x'],
 tuple: [(1,)]}
```

También se puede usar un método mas reducido para hacer el ciclo `for` como por ejemplo una comprensión de diccionario junto con la función `reduce()`

Comment: Muchas gracias, perdón solo una pregunta más, en el output en vez de ponerme solo la llave y el valor tipo: {'int':[560,10]} me pone :{<class 'int'>: [560, 10]} y asi con todos. ¿Hay alguna forma de lograr que me quede el formato sin el <class>?

Comment: en mi caso trabaje con *Google colab* y no me mostro eso, pero lo normal es que asi sea la salida, y yo no conozco una forma de evitarlo, pues la clave es la clase del objeto, vere si hay forma de sustituirlo y editare la respuesta :D

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: lo siento no encontré una forma :(. Es un precio a pagar si deseas hacer menos codigo

Comment: Al final lo logre pero toco reemplazar cada llave de la forma dict[llave nueva]=dict.pop(llave vieja) siendo llave vieja el tipo de dato que estaba en el diccionario y llave nueva el tipo de dato pero escrito entre comillas como un string , osea por ejemplo: dict['int']=dict.pop(int) y asi con todos los tipos. Es tedioso pero es lo unico que pude hacer. Igual muchas gracias.

Comment: Existe otra forma, pero esta bien

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
datos = [560, 'a', False, 10, 23.2, True, 'x', (1, ),{'a':'a'}, [23, 'b']]

dict = {}
for valor in datos:
    tipo = type(valor)
    if tipo not in dict:
        dict[tipo] = []
    dict[tipo].append(valor)
```

Recorres la lista extrayendo valores. Por cada valor obtienes su tipo con la función `type`, que retorna el nombre del tipo (`int`, `float`, ...) como un string. Así no tengo que predefinir una lista de tipos.

Uso el nombre del tipo como llave del diccionario. Cada entrada contiene una lista con los valores de ese tipo.

Si la entrada no existe (`tipo not in dict`), agrego una nueva entrada inicializada con una lista vacía.

Finalmente, agrego el valor a la entrada correspondiente del diccionario.

**Demo**

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(dict)
```

Produce:

```
{<class 'list'>: [[23, 'b']],
 <class 'bool'>: [False, True],
 <class 'float'>: [23.2],
 <class 'int'>: [560, 10],
 <class 'str'>: ['a', 'x'],
 <class 'dict'>: [{'a': 'a'}],
 <class 'tuple'>: [(1,)]}
```